# Removing paragraph tags from Wordpress posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the following php to output the content on my single.php pages

```
<?php the_content(); ?>
```

However, it puts everything (including images/img, blockquotes, etc) in `<p>` tags. I want to remove the tags from everything that isn't paragraphs.

Answer (score 2):

Use filter [**wpautop**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop). Add below in your theme function.php file

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
```

Comment: just as you wrote it? not have to be part of a function or hooked in?

Comment: Ok it worked as you said, but it removes ALL paragraph tags. I mentioned in the question I wanted it removed from everything that wasn't a paragraph. So my text paragraphs would still have <p> tags

Comment: Yes it will, or else you can install the TinyMCE Advanced] plugin. In the plugin settings you have a option "Stop removing the `<p>` and `<br />` tags when saving and show Them in the HTML editor".

Comment: I don't want to rely on a third party plugin as I won't have admin control